# Exclude certain module from optimization in Xilinx ISE 14.4

Tags: vhdl, ise, optimization

I'm synthesizing a quite large design in Xilinx ISE 14.4 and would like to exclude certain modules from optimization. Is that possible?

The design I'm synthesizing is the LEON3 microprocessor. I have modified the Integer Unit pipeline to implement triple modular redundancy. The problem is that the additional registers I have added, are being removed again by the optimization.

There seems to be a global synthesis option "remove-equivalent-registers". I have tried to turn this off and it worked for the module I have modified. But maybe this might lead to some strange behavior in other modules. So I actually would like to activate this options just for the module I modified myself.

Comment: Have a look at pages 358/359 of this http://www.xilinx.com/itp/xilinx10/books/docs/xst/xst.pdf.  I don't have any personal experience of this, but it looks like it should be relevant.  You can set that option with a directive within the HDL.

Comment: Thank you @Will Dean! Adding a line like this
`MODEL "entity_name" equivalent_register_removal={yes|no|true|false};` to my xcf-file (from page 359 in your link) solved the problem.